# Java & Javap: How to Determine Which Object Receives Invokevirtual

Tags: java, opcode, javap

I am looking through the output of Javap.  For example:

This code

```
    final Foo foo = new Foo(1,2);
    ... 
    new Callable<Integer>()
    {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception
        {
            return foo.doSomething();
        }
```

Generates:

```
        jvmOperations": [{
            "byteOffset": 0,
            "constantPoolIndex": null,
            "opCode": 42,
            "opCodeName": "aload_0",
            "type": null,
            "tagName": null,
            "tagValue": null
        }, {
            "byteOffset": 1,
            "constantPoolIndex": null,
            "opCode": 180,
            "opCodeName": "getfield",
            "type": null,
            "tagName": "Field",
            "tagValue": "val$foo:Lcom/example/graph/demo/Foo;"
        }, {
            "byteOffset": 4,
            "constantPoolIndex": null,
            "opCode": 182,
            "opCodeName": "invokevirtual",
            "type": null,
            "tagName": "Method",
            "tagValue": "com/example/graph/demo/Foo.doSomething:()Ljava/lang/Integer;"
        }, {
            "byteOffset": 7,
            "constantPoolIndex": null,
            "opCode": 176,
            "opCodeName": "areturn",
            "type": null,
            "tagName": null,
            "tagValue": null
        }]
```

So I see that the object is identified in this case by `val$foo`.  And in the class metadata

```
    "classMetaData": {
        "classId": "com/example/Main$1.class",
        "sourceName": "Main.java",
        "isInterface": false,
        "isClass": true,
        "accessModifiers": ["final"],
        "superClassName": "java/lang/Object",
        "implementedInterfaces": ["java/util/concurrent/Callable"],
        "jreTargetVersion": "51.0",
        "fields": ["val$foo"],
        "fieldModifiers": {
            "val$foo": ["final"]
        },
        "methodInformationMap": {},
        "interface": false,
        "class": true
    },
```

But now I want to find out more about the original object `foo`.  For example, I know it has this data in one of its fields:

```
        {
            "byteOffset": 37,
            "constantPoolIndex": null,
            "opCode": 18,
            "opCodeName": "ldc",
            "type": null,
            "tagName": "String",
            "tagValue": "NODE-1"
        },
```

How does the JVM know what `val$foo` points to?

Comment: The JVM knows that val$foo points to a Foo object (or some subclass of Foo), because that's the way it's declared.  And the method actually invoked depends on the class of the object actually used for the invokevirtual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a little more context to track the value the JVM stores for `foo`.

Assuming `foo` is a local variable

1. `new Foo(1,2);` is invoked
2. The result, the value of the reference to the instance, is copied and stored in the local variable `foo`
3. ...stuff...
4. The anonymous class constructor is invoked to create a new instance
5. As part of its constructor, a copy of the value of the local variable `foo` is retrieved and pushed on the stack
6. That value is popped from the stack and assigned to this `val$foo` field of the anonymous class (this is closing over that variable)
7. ...stuff...
8. When `foo.something()` is invoked, the JVM retrieves the value of the field `val$foo` of the anonymous class instance
9. The JVM dereferences that value to get the object and invokes the method on it

Comment: Thanks Sotirios, it turns out also that part of the data I need may be in the constant pool as well.